# Studio 2017 ctrl+arrow changes focus instead of skipping words

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying out `VS2017` (previous using `VS2015`), and I'm trying to navigate my code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>. Instead of the typical behavior of moving to the next or previous word, it changes the focus to different UI elements.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrows</kbd> I can get to the reference counts from CodeLens, quick actions, and the project and item dropdowns above the text editor. The same result happens when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.

How can I return to a normal text editor behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by resetting all the settings and uninstalling extensions.

To reset your settings, go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings.